# How to cd into the named directory if command not found?

Tags: zsh

When I type something which is neither a zsh builtin and no such executable is found from $PATH, zsh just reports an error. Instead, I would like zsh to check if a named directory exists with that name and cd into it.

I tried defining command_not_found_handler() function but it didn't work as it forks a sub-shell to execute that function and hence directory change is not reflected in the actual shell.

Is it something that is already possible with some settings or a new (useful?) feature?

Comment: Do you have defined your function with `()` or `{}` around the body.  If I'm not mistaken, with `{}` zsh shouldn't launch a subshell to execute the command not found handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [zsh manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Command-Execution.html#Command-Execution) states:

> If no external command is found but a function `command_not_found_handler` exists the shell executes this function with all command line arguments. (…) Note that the handler is executed in a subshell forked to execute an external command, hence changes to directories, shell parameters, etc. have no effect on the main shell.

So you can't do what you described short of patching zsh.

You could create a function for each of your named directories.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just described [AUTO_CD](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-AUTO_005fCD).

Comment: Just as a note, `shopt -s autocd` is also available in `bash` so it is not a `zsh` specific thing.

Comment: No, I'm not looking for this. I don't want to cd into a subdirectory. I want to cd to a "zsh named directories". Eg: `cd ~mydir`.