# How to silently handle the "bash: /xyz: Is a directory" error in bash shell?

Tags: bash, error-handling

In zsh, executing the directory path will cd into it. I want to make bash shell to behave the same. The idea is to check and see if the error is `bash: /xyz: Is a directory` and cd into '/xyz' and silence the error message.
For this to work I need a custom error handler. `trap` catches signals and the mentioned error does not create a signal (or does it?).

This is not about the bash script, but the actual bash shell one uses every day. Is it possible?

Comment: Umm, by default, `zsh` gives that exact same error message.

Comment: @Kusalananda totally my bad. trap "command" ERR actually works. Must look into the plugin oh-my-zsh has activated for me.

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126719/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24378/ , where answer comments (also found at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31161/) have addressed this long since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally my bad. `trap "errHandler" ERR` actually works, a typo kept me looking for solution for two hours. Must look into the plugin oh-my-zsh has activated for me by default, because zsh has no such behavior by default.

And by the way, the easy method is to use `autocd` added in bash 4.0: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/55424